# Audio for AS3 slideshow

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, slideshow

I am creating a click-through slideshow with images on keyframes, and a UI movieclip with back and next buttons.  I need to add audio explaining each image that shuts off when the user clicks either of the buttons.

Right now I set the audio to play on each page using the simple add variable/play code of:

```
var mySound:Sound = new sound_1();
mySound.play();
```

and have a stop all on both buttons:

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

This doesn't seem to be working though.  Is there a better way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
var mySound:Sound = new sound_1();;
mySound.play();

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
```

Is it possible you have a timeline loop occurring that is reactivating the mySound.play() function?